# notnoop/java-apns can't detect error

Tags: java, push

I'm using notnoop/java-apns library to push messages from my server to IOS devices.
The push works OK, messages arrives to the clients.

I'm trying to detect if the message was pushed to the client or not, but the
The problem is that I can't detect error/success of pushed message using the EnhancedApnsNotification and implements ApnsDelegate class.

The messageSendFailed & messageSent aren't called

My code

```
public class PushTest  implements ApnsDelegate {
private static pushtest instance = null;

private static ApnsService service;
private static int counter= 0;

private pushtest() {
}

static public PushTest instance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new pushtest();
        try {
            service =  APNS.newService()
                    .withCert("certPath", "password")
                    .withSandboxDestination()
                    .build();       
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

public void send(String token) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>();
    // build payload
     int now =  (int)(new Date().getTime()/1000);

    try {
         String payload = APNS.newPayload()
                .badge(3)
                .alertBody("test")
                .build();
     EnhancedApnsNotification notification = new EnhancedApnsNotification(counter++,
         now + 60 * 60 /* Expire in one hour */,
         token /* Device Token */,
         payload);
     service.push(notification);    
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("IosPush :" + e1.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public void connectionClosed(DeliveryError arg0, int arg1) {
    System.out.println("connectionClosed");     
}
@Override
public void messageSendFailed(ApnsNotification arg0, Throwable arg1) {
    System.out.println("messageSendFailed");
}
@Override
public void messageSent(ApnsNotification arg0) {
    System.out.println("messageSent");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the Delegate just isn't wired up to the service. Create a delegate, then wire it up using the builder's withDelegate(..) method.

```
public class MyApnsDelegate extends ApnsDelegateAdapter {


    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApnsDelegate.class);

    @Override
    public void messageSent(ApnsNotification apnsNotification, boolean b)
    {
        log.info("MyApnsDelegate called!");
    }
}
```

Then in the code that sets up the APNS service, APNS.newService() returns an ApnsServiceBuilder which lets you set the delegate:

```
service =  APNS.newService()
               .withCert("certPath", "password")
               .withSandboxDestination()
               .withDelegate(new MyApnsDelegate())
               .build();
```